# Can the default List View for Apex Classes be changed?

Tags: salesforce

This is more of an annoyance (not a major issue, but it messes with my productivity) than anything.

Our Salesforce organization has a couple of views for Apex Classes, and right now one of the custom List Views that filters them is first to show up when I click the navigation link "Apex Classes" (Setup > Develop > Apex Classes). I'd rather have the All List view show up. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Salesforce doesn't provide any option for defaulting the view for the classes.

Comment: By the way, how did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

Following link gives an idea to handle this,
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/List-view-on-Apex-Classes-doesn-t-default-to-quot-All-quot/td-p/201047

The basic idea is that the Apex/Page list view will use the first created list view as the default, so that users can build their own view and set it as 'Visible only to me', then everyone can get their own default list view.